# jQuery menu and "strange" behavior 

Tags: jquery, menu, drop-down-menu

I'm working on this menu: http://jsbin.com/useqa4/18

How can I prevent the divs from this behavior they have when they change? If I use `show()` alone there isn't problem, but I need to slide then and it has wrong behavior when I move fast my cursor. What can I do for this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try using .stop(true,true) before the show() function...

**EDIT:**

Here's what the problem is but I can't seem to find where to fix it. After you choose a second menu item the old one gets `style="display:block"` added to it. Hence why it is staying there.

Have you thought about taking an existing menu and customizing the look and feel, here's some:

http://devsnippets.com/article/reviews/10-brilliant-multi-level-navigation-menu-techniques.html
http://csscreator.com/tools/multimenu

Answer (score 0):

use the stop() function after you animation.
docs here for how to use it correctly.
http://api.jquery.com/stop/

hope this helps

and good look with jQuery